# writing to stdin from java to python

Tags: java, python, stdin

I am having an issue trying to write to stdin from java.

here is my python code which would be receiving the stdin input

```
import sys 
data = sys.stdin.readlines()
print data
```

I am trying to write out to stdout in java but it keeps on printing to console.

```
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(System.out));
out.write("i am writing to stdin");
out.flush();
```

However it keeps on printing in java console instead of the python shell.

Comment: Are you starting the Java process from the Python program or the other way around ?

Comment: @Titus is there a way i could start the java process from python?

Comment: yes, you can use [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html)

Comment: I don't know much about Python but a quick search revealed [this](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html). Once you start the Java process you can get its output stream and read it in the Python program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if you want to redirect a programs stdout to an other programs stdin you usually use a pipe when calling them from shell. Here's an example scenario with your code that does this:

Java side (file called App.java):

```
import java.io.*;

public class App{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(System.out));
        out.write("i am writing to stdin");
        out.flush();
    }
}
```

Python side (file called App.py):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys 
data = sys.stdin.readlines()
print data
```

Then on the shell:

First compile the java app:

```
javac App.java
```

Then call them with a pipe:

```
java App | ./App.py
```

This will result in the output:

```
['i am writing to stdin']
```